# Access to Tkinter's Text widget by background thread cause crashes

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I created a simple tkinter app, where have used two threads. Their task is to write numbers to widgets such as label and text. One thread is triggered by button (click event) and second is executed as a background thread.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from ttk import *
from Tkconstants import *
import threading, thread, time

def tl1(text,counter):
    while True:
        text.insert(END,counter)
        counter += 1
        time.sleep(2)

def tl2(label,counter):
    while True:
        label['text'] = counter
        counter += 1
        time.sleep(1)

class mainWindow():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self._initLayout()

    def _initLayout(self):

        #button
        self.button = tk.Button(self.master, text="thread1_start", command = self._task1)
        self.button.pack()

        #label
        self.label = tk.Label(self.master)
        self.label.pack()

        #text
        self.text = tk.Text(self.master, width=30)
        self.text.pack()

    def _task1(self):
        t1 = thread.start_new_thread(tl1,(self.text,1))

    def _task2(self):
        t2 = thread.start_new_thread(tl2,(self.label,1000))

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.mainWindow = mainWindow(self)

        self.mainWindow._task2() #background_thread

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

In this manner everything works fine, but if we change the background thread to display results on **text widget**, the whole app freezes.

Why background thread works fine communicating with label but causes problems with text widget? Is there any way to run it properly?

Comment: Perhaps you could use [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) rather than actual threading.

Comment: Please note, that both tasks are infinite loops and running them without threads cause the application freezing too.

Comment: Yeah, but if you continually re-register with `after` instead of using `while`, then it's not really an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tkinter isn't thread safe. You can only access widgets from the thread that created them. Your threads will need to put data on a thread-safe queue, and your GUI thread will need to poll the queue.

In your particular case you don't need threads at all. You can use the tkinter `after` method to run code periodically.

Comment: Maybe you are right and best solution is to use queues managed from the main thread, but I wonder why it works for a label widget and not for text. These threads don't affect each other so theoretically there should be no difference. `after` method used for `self.mainWindow._task2()` works, even with delay set to 1ms (probably mostly depends of app complexity and machine hardware, anyway it must wait for `mainloop` initialization). Threads have to be used, without them app window freeze at all. Thanks for this solution.

Comment: @Jarek: I don't know why it works for some widgets and not for others. That's the nature of threading issues -- the results can be somewhat non-deterministic.  I recommend _against_ using `after` with 1ms unless you truly need to do something 1000 times a second.

Comment: Yes I understand your point - 1ms is not necessary, only check it for testing purposes. But please note, that in my schema I execute it only once (in this line: `self.mainWindow._task2() #background_thread`), I do not re-register it.

Comment: My app is now working beautifully - I have rewrote it using queues. Thanks again Bryan.